# PHP errors not displayed when script run via exec()

Tags: php, error-handling, command-line-interface

I have php script that is run from other php script via exec function:

```
exec("php /home/www/someScript.php 1>> /home/www/log.txt 2>&1");
```

The log.txt contains only following error message in case of error:

```
ERROR: the server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
```

But when I run it manually using exactly same command from CLI I get following (and correct output):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object in /home/www/someScript.php on line 50
ERROR: the server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
```

What is the reason of Fatal error suppression and how can I properly output it into log?

Thanks.

Comment: Why in the name of god you are doing it this way? I mean, why not just use `include`?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos it is standalone script that is also run from crontab for example.

Comment: And by the way, you should post the code from your "someScript.php" file, otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: Doesn't matter it's standalone, there is no point of using `exec` inside PHP to call another PHP script.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Error in included script would kill the main one. I don't want that and this is simple to log separatedly. I would expect the behavior to be same no matter if I run it manually, from cron or via exec.

Comment: No, it won't. Not if you set it up properly. See [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). You should never rely on system-dependant features like `exec`, otherwise you'll keep getting weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This will not solve your problem, so is probably not an answer, but it won't fit into a comment either.

As I've said in the comments section, try using `include` along side with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler).

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext){
    echo "Error #$errno: $errstr";
    echo "\ton $errfile:$errline\n";
    echo "Stack trace:\n";
    foreach ($errcontext as $e) {
        echo "\t$e\n";
    }
});

include "/home/www/someScript.php";

restore_error_handler();
```

This way your script doesn't break when it fails, but you are not using quirky system functions. Then we can start to see what's really going on.